# GetOrder error in plugin

Tags: c#, wordpress, woocommerce

I using plugin WooCommerce.NET [Plugin link](https://github.com/XiaoFaye/WooCommerce.NET)

I try to download all orders from WP website like this.

```
 var orders = await wc.GetOrders();
        foreach (var order in orders)
        {
          Debug.WriteLine($"ID:{order.id}");

        }
```

With ID i try to count how much orders I receiving.

But I have 10 ID's in Console. On website admin I see 28 Id's.

Maybe anyone knows where is problem?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved like this.

```
var orders = await wc.GetOrders(new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                 { "per_page", "20" }});
```